# How can I fix NameError in __init__?

Tags: python

I was trying to make my first discord bot. I got this error: `NameError: name 'exceptions' is not defined`. It was in `__init__`. I guess that something is wrong with names.

Here's how my `__init__` looks like:

```
from .client import *
from .exceptions import *
from .protocol import *
from .server import *
from .uri import *
from .version import version as __version__  # noqa

__all__ = (
    client.__all__ +
    exceptions.__all__ +
    protocol.__all__ +
    server.__all__ +
    uri.__all__
)
```

If I need to add something else, tell me in comments.

Comment: `from .exceptions import *` That imports all the sub-items in `exceptions`, but does not import the exceptions module itself.  That is why the name `exceptions` is undefined.

Comment: @JohnGordon What should I do then?

Comment: Use `import exceptions`

Comment: @Barmar When i use import exceptions i get : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions', but when i do import .exceptions i get Invalid Syntax. What's next ?

Comment: The correct syntax is `from . import exceptions`

Comment: Why are you even worrying about `__all__`?  That doesn't seem like something a beginner would be concerned with.